# Understanding Docker Container Internals in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I think to understood how fabric mainly works and how consens is reached. What I am still missing in the documentation is the part of what happens inside of a docker container of fabric to take part in communication process.

So, communication starting from a client (e.g. an app) takes place in using gRPC messages between peers and orderer.

But what happens inside of the containers?

I imagine it for myself as a process that is only receiving gRPC message and answering them in using functions in the background of a peer/orderer, to hands out its response for further processing in another unit like the client to collect the responses of multiple peers for a smart contract.

But what happens really inside a container? I mean, a container spawns, when the docker image file is loaded and launched by the yaml config file. But what is started there inside of it (is there only a single peer binary started, e.g. like the command "peer node start") - I mean the compiled go binary file "peer" only?? What is listening? What is responding there? I discovered only one port for every container that is exposed out. This seems for me to be the gate for gRPC (cause it is often used as Port ID: **51).

The same questions goes for the orderer, the chaincode and the cli. How are they talking to each other or is gRPC the only way of communication and processing (excluded of the discovery service and gossip, how is this started inside of the containers (in using the yaml files for lauchun only or is there further internal configuration or a startupscript in the image files (cause I cannot look inside the images, only login on running containers while runtime).

Answer (score 1):

When your client sends request to one of the peers, peer instance checks if requested chaincode (**CC**) installed on it. **If CC not installed**: Obviously you'll get an error.

**If CC is installed**: Peer checks if a dedicated container is already started for the given CC and corresponding version. **If container is started**, peer sends transaction request to that CC instance and returns back the response to your client after signing the transaction. Signing guarantees that response is really sent by that peer.

**If container not started:** 
It builds a docker image and starts that instance (docker container). New image would be based on one of the hyperledger images. i.e. if your CC is GO, then `hyperledger/baseos`, which is very basic linux os, will be used. This new image contains CC binary and META-DATA as well.

That peer instance is using underlying (your) machine's docker server to do all of those. That's the reason why we need to pass `/var/run:/host/var/run` into volume mapping and `CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock` into environment variables.

Once the CC container starts, it connects to its parent peer node which is defined with 
`CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS` attribute. Peer dictates to child (probably during image creation) to use this address, so they obey. Peer node defines its own listen URL with `CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS` attribute.

About your last question; communication is with gRPC in between nodes also with clients. If TLS is enabled, then it's for sure secure communication. Entry point for orderers to know about peers and peers know about other organizations' peers is the definition of anchor peers defined during channel creation. Discovery service is running in peer nodes, so they can hold a close to real-time network layout. Discovery service also provides peers' identity, that's how clients can detect other organizations' peers when endorsement policy requires multiple organizations' endorsement policy (i.e. if policy look like `AND(Org1MSP.member, Org2MSP.member)`).